# Libgdx Group Size Issue

Tags: libgdx, size

To make my question clearer , I created a simple test class as below.

```
`public void create () {
    stage = new Stage();
    // GP
    Texture texture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/badlogic.jpg"));
    TextureRegion tr = new TextureRegion(texture1);
    Image image = new Image(tr);
    Group gp = new Group();
    ImageButton ib = new ImageButton(new Image(tr).getDrawable());
    ib.setSize(90, 256);
    gp.addActor(ib);
    gp.setPosition(0, 0);
    stage.addActor(gp);
    gp.debugAll();
}`
```

The size of badlogic logo is 256*256. I set it to 90*256 in the test.But the outcome looks like this http://imgsrc.baidu.com/forum/w%3D580/sign=fb0e4402d21373f0f53f6f97940e4b8b/0958c32397dda1448779b0cbb1b7d0a20df486e2.jpg
If i set the  image size before sending it to imagebutton, then it will rendered  as 256*256 ,the full original size. This function is so simple. I can not figure out where is going wrong.

Comment: Please consider posting some code to identify better the problem. on top of my head, libgdx table cells have expand() and fill() methods which can be used to stretch images to fill an area. But without code it is hard to get the correct problem.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, last update of Libgdx project is 1.4.1: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html*

The problem is the Drawable object that you are sending to the ImageButton, if you want to change the size of the Image or Texture before adding it to the ImageButton (so you will solve the problem asked), **you will just need to use the `.setBounds()` method**

I write down a little example:

***1. Initialize Image object with your image file:***

```
`Image image = new Image( new Texture ( Gdx.Files.internal("yourPathFile.png") ) );`
```

**2. .setBounds() javadoc: (x coordinate, y coordinate, width of the image, height of the image)**

```
image.setBounds(0f, 0f, 50f, 60f)
```

3. then you can **send the image to the ImageButton object as Drawable**.
   `ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(image.getDrawable());'

That's all.

Here you have some constructors of ImageButton object from the Libgdx official javadoc.

[image: Libgdx ImageButton Constructors javadoc]

**See also:**

- *Release versions:* http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/
- *ImageButton javadoc:* http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed solution. I tried the way you described but it still does not work right. The image on imagebutton turned very large if  I set its size before sending it to imagebutton. I doubt this problem  only happens on my currently using gdx version because I used libgdx about 1.5 year before and I did not come across this kind of issue.Can you tell me which version of libgdx are you using?

Comment: Don't worry, you can use .setBounds() method also for ImageButton. Try with that. :)

Comment: It still does not work. I edited my question again and make it much more simple.You can check it out.I don't know how could this simple test go wrong.